# Difference Between Spotfire Web player client and Spotfire Web player server

Tags: configuration, tibco, spotfire

I want to configure the Tibco Spotfire and confused with 2 terms - 
1) Spotfire Web player client
2) Spotfire Web player server

Can anyone help to know the difference between Spotfire Web player client and Spotfire Web player server.

As per my understanding, I can install Spotfire Server and Spotfire Web player on one machine. And Spotfire developer on various machines.
Now I am confused with a new term as 'Spotfire Web player client'. How I can use this client for the Spotfire configuration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Spotfire Webplayer Server is the machine that will interact with the Spotfire Server, much like the Professional(Pro) client does. It should reside in the same data center as the Spotfire Server. The Spotfire Webplayer Client (consumer) is the interface from any machine to the Spotfire Webplayer. It is accessed via your local browser. Data communication happen between the Webplayer and Server. The client will just have mostly pictures and JavaScript, etc. 
While with the Business Author license you can now do some authoring from the Webplayer Client, most of the Authoring would normally be done with the Spotfire Professional Client. So in a sense you can think of the Spotfire Webplayer Server as a remote 'Professional client' with stripped down functionality that is accessed remotely via your browser (the Webplayer client).

Answer (score 4):

Spotfire Web player server is the machine on which you host Spotfire Web player application. Spotfire Web player client is this web application hosted on server. You can still host Web player app on the same machine on which you 'open' it as a client in Web browser.

It is like with any other web app. Those apps must be hosted on some servers and when hosted they can be 'opened' in browsers from other machines than those on which they are served but still they also can be opened on the same machines.

Comment: Stackoverflow it the web application. You can open it on your machine in browser but still it also can be opened from the servers on which it is hosted.

Answer (score 3):

TIBCO does a really good job documenting and explaining this in their 
[TIBCO Spotfire® Web Player 7.0 Installation and Configuration Manual](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/spotfire_web_player/7.0.1/doc/pdf/TIB_sfire_webp_7.0.1_installation.pdf) chapter 1 section 1.2 page 5

[Basic Spotfire Architecture Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4Wot.png)